# Illegal indirection error due to show function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My function `void show(const SOP & sop)` which is supposed to output a set of ordered pairs by calling a different show function that outputs ordered pairs defined below is telling me there is an error of illegal indirection, code C2100, but I am not sure why this is the case.

SOP stands for set of ordered pairs. OP stands for ordered pairs. 
All help is appreciated.

```
#include <algorithm> // pair
#include <iostream>
#include <set> // set
#include <cassert> // assert
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<unsigned, unsigned> OP;
typedef set<OP> SOP;
void show(const OP & op);
void show(const SOP & sop);
int main() {
    show(OP(7,3));
    SOP x((1, 1), (3, 2), (5,4));
    show(x);
}

void show(const OP & op) {
    cout << "(" << op.first << "," << op.second << ")" << endl;
}
void show(const SOP & sop) {
    for (const OP & n: sop) {
        show(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message and a full [mcve] (this one is missing the definitions of functions like `makeOP`)

Comment: @UnholySheep To be fair, this is much closer to an MCVE than we normally get. Presumably the first three lines of main can be deleted without affecting the error.

Comment: Seems the first few lines from main have been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this code

```
SOP x((1, 1), (3, 2), (5, 4));
```

should be using braces not parens

```
SOP x{{1, 1}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
```

With that change everything  seems in order.